# Make CSS skip over divs when using %

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<middle-panel-file checked="data.checked" class="ng-isolate-scope">
<div ng-show="checked.length() == 1" class="" style="height:  100%;">
<div ng-show="checked.getSingleFile()" class="" style="height:  100%;">
<div class="k-tabstrip-wrapper" style=" height:  100%;">
<div kendo-tab-strip="" data-role="tabstrip" tabindex="0" class="k-widget k-header k-tabstrip" role="tablist" style="height:  100%;">
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" style="padding: 5px; display: block;height: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;" class="ng-scope k-content k-state-active" id="8251f46a-2f98-4c4a-aebd-c747a9128c85-1" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true">
```

Only deepest element has *visible* content and I want to have it be 100% the `height` of the topmost element. Is there a way to do this without also putting that style on each `div` like I have done?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention that Kendo overwrites height styling, but generally not display styling, so the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504904/divs-height-100-inheriting-grandparents-height-and-overflowing-parents-h) could be a solution, but I can't figure out the correct combination of table display styling.

Comment: use a css-file and write `div{height:100%}`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
#topmost-element div {
    height:100%;
}
```

That should make all DIVs within your topmost element have a height of 100%.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that some of the tabs content also contained divs; I can use your suggestion and add a few styles to the tabs-content, but it might cause issues if their content is changed. Is there a way to use table displays like in this [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504904/divs-height-100-inheriting-grandparents-height-and-overflowing-parents-h) to do it? W3School isn't very specific on which of the table-cell/row/column display values I should use. Kendo also overwrites the height value of the ng-repeat element and Kendo can be finnicky when overwritten.

Comment: Not sure about that, but what about something like this to override any DIVs inside your tabs:
`#topmost-element .tab div {
    height:auto;
}`